# how to nest multiple python function to create a sort of pipeline?

Tags: python

Hello i have 3 functions f1(), f2() and f3(). The output of the previous is the input of the next. meaning output = f3(f2(f1(data))).

instead of writing

```
def outp(data):
    o1 = f1(data)
    o2= f2(o1)
    o3 = f3(02)
    return o3
output=outp(data)
```

is there a way to this by simply providing a list of functions to some other general function and let it handle the chaining together?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply run a `for` loop with an assignment:

```
>>> f1 = int
>>> f2 = float
>>> f3 = lambda x: x * 2
>>> i = '3'
>>> for func in (f1, f2, f3):
...     i = func(i)
...     print(i)
... 
3
3.0
6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across your question and I found it really interesting.

Here is my approach on a pipeline of functions:

```
def call_pipeline(transition_list, *args):
    """
    transition_list = [func1, func2, func3...
                       ]
    - func1 output is the input for func2 etc
    """

    result = args
    for f in transition_list:
        result = f(*result)

    print(*result)

def f1(x, y):
    return [x + y]

def f2(z):
    return [z**2, z]

def f3(w, r):
    return [w * r]

def f4(t):
    return ["Final", t]

def test_pipeline():
    transition_list = [f1, f2, f3, f4]
    call_pipeline(transition_list, *[1, 2])
```

As long as you make sure that every function inside the pipeline returns a list and the next function can properly process the output of the previous one, this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy to define a `compose` function that handles simple single-argument functions:

```
def compose(*args):
    if not args:
        return lambda x: x  # Identity function
    else:
        return compose(args[0], compose(args[1:]))

outp = compose(f3, f2, f1)  # Note the order of the arguments
```

You can also use the `reduce` function (`functools.reduce` in Python 3):

```
outp = reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), [f3, f2, f1], lambda x:x)
```

You can omit the third argument if you are certain the list of functions won't be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a composition function that operates on a sequence of functions:

```
def compose(a, b):
    def fcn(*args, **kwargs):
        return a(b(*args, **kwargs))
    return fcn

def compose_all(*fcns):
    return reduce(compose, fcns)

def compose_all_1(*fcns):
    return reduce(compose, fcns, lambda x: x)
```

The function `compose` is the basic building block that takes two functions and returns their composition.  With this elementary idiom you can extend this to an arbitrary sequence of functions in `compose_all`.  The variant `compose_all_1` works even on a 1- or 0-element input sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pipeline builder, that you can reuse to build pipelines.

Each pipeline is a function that can be invoked with one argument or none (rarely used).
When a pipeline is called it sequentially run every functions with previous function return value as argument.

```py
from functools import reduce
import warnings

# pipeline function builder
def pipe(*funcs):
    """
Usage:
pipe(
  lambda x: x+1,
  lambda x: x+20
)(50)

Order of execution of functions is FIFO.
FIFO = First In First Out
    """
    # if no arguments return an identity function and warn the developer
    if not funcs:
        warnings.warn("""pipe() is useless when called without arguments.
Please provide functions as arguments or remove call to pipe().
        """)
        return lambda x=None: x # Identity function
    
    def runner(value=None):
        return reduce(lambda acc, curr: curr(acc), funcs, value)
    return runner


# test 1
pipeline = pipe()
print(pipeline())
# None


# test 2
pipeline = pipe()
print(pipeline(8))
# 8


# test 3
pipeline = pipe(
    lambda unused: 50
)
print(pipeline())
# 50


# test 4 -> Real Usage
pipeline = pipe(
    lambda age: age >= 18,
    lambda is_adult: 'Adult' if is_adult else 'Minor'
)
print(pipeline(12))
# Minor
print(pipeline(20))
# Adult
```